# Trouble with haskell IO

Tags: haskell, io

I am having difficulty understanding exactly how haskell processes input and output. As an example, here I am trying to take command line arguments of a list of data files, and put the contents of these files into a list of lists of doubles. After some research, my best implementation is:

```
{- Read Doubles from input, sent them to a list -}
getDoubles :: Handle -> IO [Double]
getDoubles handle = do
        done <- hIsEOF handle
        if done then return []
        else do
                first <- hGetLine handle
                rest <- getDoubles handle
                return (read first : rest)

{- Send the data to the handle -}
sendData :: Handle -> [Double] -> IO()
sendData handle (x:[]) = hPrint handle x
sendData handle (x:xs) = do
        hPrint handle x
        sendData handle xs


main = do
        args <- getArgs 
        handleList <- mapM (\x -> openFile x ReadMode) args
        sendData stdout  (fmap getDoubles handleList)
```

But this is giving me an error because getDoubles returns type IO [Double], not just [Double].
What can I do to map my getDoubles function over my list of file handles?

Comment: `sendData` takes a `[Double]`, but you have a collection of `[Double]`s, one for each file. How do you want to square away this mismatch?

Answer (score 2):

Just as you did with `openFile` (which also does IO), you can use `mapM`:

```
main = do
    args <- getArgs
    handleList <- mapM (\x -> openFile x ReadMode) args
    doubless <- mapM getDoubles handleList
    sendData stdout doubless
```

You may also like `readFile`, as in:

```
parse :: String -> [Double]
parse = map read . lines

main = do
    args <- getArgs
    doubless <- mapM readFile args
    mapM (print . parse) doubless
```

Comment: (This answer glosses over the mismatch between `sendData :: ... -> [Double] -> ...` and `doubless :: [[Double]]`. I will fix it up if john answers my comment to this effect on their question.)